# How does the Announcer badge work?

Tags: support, badges

The Announcer Badge was recently given for this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2530/19341), but there are no links, neither in nor out.

And how does it work at all? Does it matter if I link a question or an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click the link button to the lower left of a question, it appends your user number to the end of the link. So when people visit that link, it identifies their IP addresses with your account.

[This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3817/7850) is "my" link to this question.

[This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3817/how-does-the-announcer-badge-work/3818#3818) is the URL in my browser.

Comment: A [related thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3445/5363)

Comment: Which immediately makes me wonder: from memory, or not? (@t.b.)

Comment: I remembered that thread... :)